# Adding apostrophes into queries

Tags: asp.net, syntax, apostrophe

I have a query which gets the text from a textbox and inputs it into the database.

It works fine if the value is something like `Taylor` but errors when it's `O'Neill` because the apostrophe gives a syntax error `unclosed quotation mark`

Is there a way to add `O'Neill` to the database with the apostrophe still there?

I don't want to replace it with a double single quote I want it to be put in the database as it shows.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to insert data into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **double single quotes**, you won't end up with **double single quotes** in your database. You will end up with **only one single quote**.

The **doble single quotes** is just a way to **ESCAPE** a **single quote** in a SQL sentence. So, when you do a:

```
> insert into your_table (name) values ('O''neil');
```

The value `O'neil` will actually be inserted in the database.

If your database is **PostgreSQL**, there are other ways of manipulating strings. For example using `$$`:

```
> insert into your_table (name) values ($$O'neil$$);
```

Will insert `O'neil` in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at **Step 4. Use Command Parameters for SQL Queries** in [this document by Microsoft patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb355989). Not only will this solve your quoting issues, but it will also prevent SQL injection attacks and other **Very Bad Things™** from happening.

Comment: Using parameters isn't really an option for me now all the current queries that i'm editing from someone else's work use openquery and are done without parameters I don't want to have to re-write the whole page atm but +1 for info on SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

You can escape an apostrophe by doubling it (`''`) - a single apostrophe will be inserted.

So, inserting `O''Neill` will result in `O'Neill` inserted into the DB.

However, the fact that you need to do so suggests that you are using embedded SQL that is open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201%28SQL.90%29.aspx), you will not be as vulnerable and you will not need to resort to escaping apostrophes.

Comment: He/she mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Pablo - escaping it _will_ insert a single quote into the DB.

Comment: @Pablo - my point is that he assumes that escaping will result in _two_ apostrophes being inserted. That assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your SQL query with double '' just fine, the database recognize the escape caracter and saves only one.

Why you dont want the double single quote solution?